# Cordova API call works fine in Android and Postman but returns null in iOS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, safari, postman

API request in Cordova app works fine in Android device but the same code returns data as null when running in iOS device. 
If I copy the request from Safari inspector as a cURL and hit it in postman, it works fine.

I see that **request Content-type** is set as **application/json**, but the response **content-type** is **text/html**

response also returns another header '**content-encoding**' as '**gzip**'

Can anyone help me fix this please ?